# laravel "Method [hasTooManyLoginAttempts] does not exist."

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am creating a custom login in laravel 5 with throttling but I keep on getting the above error:

> laravel "Method [hasTooManyLoginAttempts] does not exist."

This is my code:

```
public function loginUsers(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request, [
    'email' => 'required',
   'password' => 'required',

]);
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
    $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

    return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
}

$email      = $request->get('email');
$password   = $request->get('password');
$remember   = $request->get('remember');

if ($this->auth->attempt([
    'email'     => $email,
    'password'  => $password,

], $remember == 1 ? true : false)) {
     $request->session()->regenerate();
    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return redirect()->route('front-product.index');

   }
    else {                       
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
       return redirect()->back()
        ->with('message','Incorrect username or password')
        ->with('status', 'danger')
        ->withInput();
   }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share the code that you are trying to run?

Comment: Are you using the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait? `use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;`